# How to automatically add unique key according to user input and then update it in python

Tags: python

I have a problem creating a dictionary key that is unique and comes from the user. And I don't know how to add it. So here is what I desire:

```
Sale: blue 5
5 blue so far
Sale: orange 2
2 orange so far
Sale: blue 3
8 blue so far
Sale:
```

how do I update it?

```
object1 = {}

line = input('Sales: ')
while line:
  parts = line.split()
  key = parts[0]
  val = (parts[1])*1
  object1[key] = int(val)
  print(object1)
  line = input('Sales: ')
```

Firstly, i want to know how to add unique key to dictionary and second how do i add it.

Comment: look into `defaultdict(int)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe as full code:

```
object1 = {}
line = input('Sales: ')
while line:
  a,b = line.split()
  object1[a]=object1.get(a,0)+int(b)
  print(object1[a],a,'so far')
  line = input('Sales: ')
```

Example output:

```
Sales: blue 5
5 blue so far
Sales: blue 6
11 blue so far
Sales: red 2
2 red so far
Sales: orange 2
2 orange so far
Sales: red 8
10 red so far
Sales: orange 1
3 orange so far
Sales:
```

**Explanation:**

1. split the line
2. create a new key, called whatever is `a` then add the original key if it's in there to `b` already otherwise, add `b` to zero
3. make the print statement
4. as in the while check if `line` it's true, if it is, continue with other input, otherwise, break

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
object1[key] = int(val)
```

to

```
object1[key] = object.get(key, 0) + int(val)
```

Or use `object1 = defaultdict(int)` instead of `{}` (needs `from collections import defaultdict`) and `object1[key] += int(val)`.

EDIT: Functioning code:

```
object1 = {}

line = input('Sales: ')
while line:
  parts = line.split()
  key = parts[0]
  val = (parts[1])*1
  object1[key] = object1.get(key, 0) + int(val)
  print(object1)
  line = input('Sales: ')
```

Interaction log:

```
Sales: blue 7
{'blue': 7}
Sales: white 3
{'blue': 7, 'white': 3}
Sales: blue 10
{'blue': 17, 'white': 3}
```

Comment: how do i add the values tho.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Have you tried modifying your code in one of the two ways I suggested?

Comment: Then you must not have done it correctly, because it works on my end. You just need to replace one line. What specifically "doesn't work"? Do you get an error, if not what happens? Saying "didn't work" is like going to the doctor and saying "something's wrong, now fix me".

Comment: so .get doesnt work and if i use object1[key] += int(val), it would do the same as the program i was running before.

Comment: Again, what does "doesn't work" mean? And no, `+=` is not the same as `=`, therefore not equivalent. Besides, don't mix the two approaches; either go with `.get` and normal dict, or with `+=` and the `defaultdict`. I'll post my full code (with the one-line replacement) that is verified to do what you wanted, so you can compare.

Comment: what if i only want the value of only one key and not the whole dictionary. for example, when you type in white 3, i only want to output 3 'white':3 not the whole dictionary.

Comment: Then `print(object1[key])` and not `print(object1)`.

Comment: it only outputs the value. for example 5 instead of  5 white.

Comment: Then output the key and the value: `print(object1[key], key)`. This doesn't have nothing to do with the question you asked. You should read more on [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) and the [`print` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the current time for your key, if you don't need multiple keys per second.  If you want multiple keys per second, you can do something like:

time.asctime() + str(random.randint(0,1000))

Then, you can build and use the key as follows:

```
mykey = time.asctime() + str(random.randint(0,1000))
mydict = {}
mydict[mykey] = "myval"
```

Comment: I am not looking at the seconds. I am looking at adding the key if the user inputs it again.

Comment: Change object1[key] = val, to: object1[key] = object1.get(key, 0) + int(val)